# Value of Arraylist is unexpected

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I have this method that adds temp to xy array.

```
    public void printBoard(int temp[][],int type){
        if(type == 1) { 
            xyArray.add(new Array(temp));
            numberOfSolutionsXY++;
        }
    }
```

`xyArray` is global and declared as

`public ArrayList<Array> xyArray = new ArrayList();`

When I check its value before exiting the method `printBoard`, it prints the expected 2d array. But when I go to another method, the value of `xyArray` is different. It has the value of the other Arraylist.

I checked back and forth many times, I did not just mistype the parameter. It's not happening only on `xyArray`, the same happens to other arraylists: `regArray`, `xArray` and `yArray`

This is how I check the value
`System.out.println("\n xy \n"+xyArray.toString());`

I do `solveBoard` method and tries to add the expected value of arrays but different values were appended. They were all the same.

```
                problemArray.add(new Array(board));

                solveBoard(board,0,0,4);
                if(numberOfSolutions>0)
                    solutionArray.add(new ArrayList(regularArray));

                solveBoard(board,0,0,3);
                if(numberOfSolutionsX>0)
                    solutionArray.add(new ArrayList(xArray));

                if(dimension%2==1){
                    solveBoard(board,0,0,2);
                    if(numberOfSolutionsY>0)
                        solutionArray.add(new ArrayList(yArray));

                    solveBoard(board,0,0,1);
                    if(numberOfSolutionsXY>0)
                        solutionArray.add(new ArrayList(xyArray));
                }

                solutionsArray.add(new ArrayList(solutionArray));
                System.out.println("\nsolutions\n"+regularArray.toString());
```

All of them have the value of `problemArray`. Even though i placed `problemArray.add(new Array(board));` at the bottom, they still get its value.

This is the class `Array` i've made

```
public class Array {
    int[][] array;
    public Array(int[][] initialArray){
        array = initialArray;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String x = "";
        for(int i = 0;i<array[0].length;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<array[0].length;j++)
                x+=array[i][j];
            x+="\n";
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

Full code [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=83319825346310059171)

Comment: You're probably shadowing the object.

Comment: Can you explain the shadowing part @MarounMaroun? I really dont know that kind of thing and im a newbie in java

Comment: Can you please post more of your code ?

Comment: A variable or an object are shadowed if there is another variable/object with the same name that is closer in scope. I'm not sure this is the issue you're having, please post more of your code.

Comment: @MarounMaroun how can I fix this?

Comment: @CrazyGirl read about shadowing variables, try to understand it, check whether you've shadowed variables or not, fix it. Post another parts of your code and you'll get a better help.

Comment: What is this class `Array` have you written it ?

Comment: Yes, I have. Added to the question @NitinDandriyal

Comment: How do you initialize each of problemArray, solutionsArray, and regularArray?

Comment: `public ArrayList<Array> regularArray = new ArrayList();` 

`public ArrayList<Array> problemArray = new ArrayList();` 

`public ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Array>>> solutionsArray = new ArrayList<>();`
@PatriciaShanahan

Comment: Please add code to original post only, and try to be crisp and clear. Happy asking.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I think I haven't shadowed my variables. But if it is really shadowed, I wasn't able to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to rename your "Array" class, for example to "MyArray"
2. And i suppose there are some troubles with Array class constructor.
   Try to copy initialArray in to your local variable.

public class MyArray {

```
int[][] localArray;

public MyArray(int[][] initialArray) {
  localArray = initialArray.clone();
  for (int i = 0; i < initialArray.length; i++) {
     localArray[i] = initialArray[i].clone();
  }
}

public String toString() {
  // ...
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the effort :)